# To know precompiled header is used

Tags: visual-c++

I have `a.cpp` that is used in several projects. Some of them are using precompiled headers, others - not. Depending on this I must add or remove line :

```
#include <stdafx.h>
```

Is it possible somehow play with `#define` to make this in automatic way?

UPD.
I can't use empty `stdafx.h` file in case when precompiled headers are not used because I got strange behaviour in my situation when `a.cpp` is placed in project sub directory `libA`. In this case projects that use precompiled header must have line:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
```

and projects that are not using PCH must have line:

```
#include "..\stdafx.h"
```

Wice versa is not working. Actually I still can't understand this behavior. I would like to have `a.cpp` file identical for all projects.

Comment: Why do you add the same file a.cpp to two projects? Wouldn't it be better to move this file to an individual library?

Comment: I have placed two copies of a.cpp file in projects subdirectories libA. I need to save my projects in SVN and I need to use libA like external. After some experiments with turtoise SVN client I found that externals can only be placed in in project subdirectory and not outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can include a preprocessor define in the project settings for those projects which use precompiled headers, and then base the inclusion of `stdafx.h` based on its existence. Using your example, libA's C++ settings should include `/D USE_PCH`, and then in a.cpp:

```
#ifdef USE_PCH
 #include <stdafx.h>
#else
 #include "../stdafx.h"
#endif
```

To ensure that the define and precompiled header settings remain in sync, you could create a property sheet with both settings, and link it to your project. However, if it were me, I would just disable precompiled headers for the files which are shared between libraries. Unless the PCH is very large, and the number of shared sources also very large, the compilation time savings likely won't outweigh the maintenance of this approach.

Comment: ' just disable precompiled headers for the files which are shared' -- thank you!